# Unidirectional many-to-many relationship + Entity Framework Core + fluent api

Tags: entity-framework-core, fluent

I wanted to create unidirectional relation between `Author` and `Skill`.

My models are as below:

```
public class Author: Entity
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Skill : Entity
{
    ...
}
```

I want to configure it using EF Core's fluent API basic idea is not to create models based on the persistence layer's requirement.

My configuration is as below :

```
builder.HasMany(r => r.Skills).WithMany("NavigationNotRequired");
```

Comment: What is a "unidirectional many-to-many relationship"?

Comment: *"basic idea is not to create models based on the persistence layer's requirement*" Well, when it is really data model requirement (mandatory) as in this case, what really are you expecting - the framework won't adjust for your requirements, so you either adjust your requirements, or use separate models, or use another ORM.

Comment: EF Core documentation for [Many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) is crystal clear in that regard: *"Many to many relationships **require** a collection navigation property on **both** sides."*

Comment: What version are you using? 3.1 or 5.0? Efcore5.0 has support for many-to-many out of the box

Comment: Whatever you guys are trying... this still is a very bad idea.

Comment: In my example, Author can have multiple skills so I need a relationship between them but  I don't want Author to be part of Skill, as a skill for me is an independent entity and author should have at least one skill. I do agree with @IvanStoev. Any suggestions, how we can store this domain model using EF core fluent API.

Answer (score 2):

Support for unidirectional many-to-many relationships is now available in Entity Framework Core 7.

In your case, it would look like:

```
builder.HasMany(r => r.Skills).WithMany();
```

Comment: How would one actually add, in this case Skills, to the Author class? I'm not able to directly add them to the List of skills

Comment: Adding to the list would depend on the data type you are using. In the example, the skills are stored in an `ICollection`, which has an `Add` method, so the skills can be added by using `author.Skills.Add(newSkill)`. Or you can add your own method to the `Author` class, i.e. `author.AddSkill(newSkill)`.